# using pytest-variables in a test module to get public variables

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I created a json file with

```json
"create_url":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxurl"
```

then create a python test file that contain  the method that I use for test

```
@pytest.mark.regression
@pytest.mark.smoke
def test_create_tenant():
    accounts = Accounts()
    accounts.create_tenant()
```

then create a method in class accounts

```
def create_tenant(self,variables, **kwargs):
    customr_url= variables['create_tenant']
```

when I run this I get  TypeError: create_tenant() missing 1 required positional argument: 'variables'
so I updated the test method with

```
def test_create_tenant():
    accounts = Accounts()
    accounts.create_tenant(variables)
```

and I get
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

here is the plugin docshttps://pypi.org/project/pytest-variables/

try to pass global variables to test ut it is fail

Answer (score 0):

thanks
I solved it , and here is the solution
def test_create_tenant(variables):
accounts = Accounts()
accounts.create_tenant(variables['create_tenant'])